How can an exported nftables ruleset end up crashing on import?
nftables' import and export formats are incompatible.
If there are rules with 'counter' things in them, an exported ruleset with
    nftables list ruleset > ruleset.conf
    nftables -f ruleset.conf

will fail to import with the following message;
Error: syntax error, unexpected counter

For example the following kind of line in the export will create this problem;
meta l4proto ipv6-icmp icmpv6 type  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept

(There's a few dozen of these)
I have no idea what the originally created rules were, only that this particular system is in this inconsistent state, where it can export its firewall ruleset, but can no longer import the resulting thing, as it contains things of type NULL.
Does anyone have an idea; How exactly could this happen?
Am I correct in thinking that these 'meta' things don't have any impact on what packets the firewall actually accepts and they're safe to remove?
